# Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim usage Best Practices

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

I have created a semaphore instance on top of this class

```
public static SemaphoreSlim _zReportSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 500);
```

And somewhere in my code i need to retrieve and send some data.

```
while (_isRunning)
{
    try
    {
        xBsonDocument = null;
        //I think its very clear in this line...
        MongoDBDAO.xGetInstance().GetZReportData(ref xBsonDocument);

        foreach (BsonDocument item in xBsonDocument)
        {
            try
            {
                ThreadObject xThreadObject = new ThreadObject();
                xThreadObject.m_strTerminalId = item.GetValue("_id")["TERMINAL_ID"].ToString();
                xThreadObject.m_strZNo = item.GetValue("_id")["Z_NO"].ToString();

                m_xBuildAndSendZReportThread = 
                    new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(vBuildAndSendZReport));
                m_xBuildAndSendZReportThread.Start(xThreadObject);
            }
            catch (Exception xException)
            {
                xException.TraceError();
                continue;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(m_litleStepQTime); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception xException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(m_bigStepQTime);
        Trace.vInsertError(xException);
        continue;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(m_iSleepTime);
}
```

This thread targeting to send files to ftp

```
        private void vBuildAndSendZReport(object prm_objParameters)
        {
            _zReportSemaphore.Wait();
            RetriveDataFromMongoAndSend();
            _zReportSemaphore.Release();
        }
```

In this structure; if i don't use a semaphore it has working great but sometimes thread count overloading the CPU or Memory usage and machine has been crushing.

1- How can i provide control over data usage (ballancing, isolating threads  etc.) with this slim semaphore?

2- Can I use SemaphoreSlim  for this type of job in production? What can be the advantages and disadvantages of using such a workflow organization like this?
**Does it improve performance?** in my special case

3- Is there another alternative that will provide system resource management and will wrap up the technical exception management

**Update:**
I asked this question during a job I did a long time ago. After solving the problem, I realized that I did not return.

In the above example, the report sending job was happening in the file sharing environment. Other solutions are possible, such as using a CDN.

The question was: Why should I use a thread if it can't keep me informed about what it's doing, if it doesn't tell me if it has had successful results? Why should I use SemaphoreSlim for example!?

yes, of course it can be done with async programming. but I didn't want to include this library in related environment. It had to be. I'm sure this situation is needed in many codes.

my solution was this: I eliminated the possibility of the exception in the code that was throwing the exception. so i synced the conflict with the thread outside the app. I made something like a threadpool. It worked flawlessly as a consumer. I did this by setting up a custom timing mechanism.

Regardless, I still agree. A thread should be set up to carry information about the job it is doing. I'm not talking about writing a Mutex object in between. Thread itself can carry this information.

By the way, I gave points to those who answered. Because they made the right comments according the question.

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help

Comment: Why don't you use `Task[]` or `List<Task>` instead of using good old threads ? [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) may prove useful as well.

Comment: Well, you can control that by simply defining how many Tasks are executing in parallel. Tasks also allows you to [use all cpu cores](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/362996/Multi-core-programming-using-Task-Parallel-Library) rather then just one as it usually is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the first hit on Google for "Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim usage Best Practices", so I would like to add 1 remark:

At least this code:

```cs
semaphore.Wait();
DoSomeThing();
semaphore.Release();
```

should be at the minimum:

```cs
semaphore.Wait();
try
{
    DoSomeThing();
}
finally
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```

Or else you might end up NEVER releasing the semaphore again if an exception occurs in `DoSomeThing()`.

And in async programming, consider using:

```cs
await semaphore.WaitAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any event when semaphore ends its all threads

No. It's not even clear what that might mean. For example, what do you want to happen if, due to thread-scheduling issues, you have just one running thread in the semaphore at the moment, and that thread completes, releasing the semaphore, before one or more other threads even get to try to acquire the semaphore?

The semaphore has no way to detect this condition as different from every thread being done.

If you want to know when some collection of asynchronous operations has completed, you'll need to wait on that specifically. You have a number of options in .NET, including:

1. Call `Thread.Join()` on all of the thread objects you've started.
2. Use `Task` to run your asynchronous tasks instead of `Thread`, and use `Task.WhenAll()` (or less preferably, `Task.WaitAll()`) to wait for them to complete.
3. Use `CountdownEvent`. Call `AddCount()` for each task you start, have each task call `Signal()` when it's done, and then wait on the `CountdownEvent`.

By the way, the code you posted is suspect in other ways:

1. Why are you specifying a maximum count for the `SemaphoreSlim`, and why is this maximum not the same as your initial count? Do you actually expect to call `Release()` more often than you call `Wait()`?
2. Code that calls `Thread.Sleep()` is often incorrect. It's not clear why you are doing that, but it's likely there are better ways to solve whatever issue you're trying to address with those calls.

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't say for sure that those things are wrong. But there's a low likelihood of them being right. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what response from the previous two comments you are expecting. If my answer hasn't addressed your question fully, please explain in what way it hasn't. Feel free to ask for specific clarification of the answer in the comments. I don't see anything in the comments you posted so far that I can actually act on. :(